# OpenCV linear blending and spatial addition

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv

I am currently trying to write a C++ program that is able to extract ROI from the Y component of an image and watermark that particular ROI. 
I am currently stuck at the implementation of the watermarking technique.
Upon further research , I saw the addweighted function in OpenCV and I understand that it is an implementation of linear blending.

What i want to ask is that is alpha blending considered something like a spatial addition between the pixel of the original image and the watermark ? 
If not , could anyone  explain the difference between alpha blending and a spatial addition between two images ?

Thank you in advance for any help rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% what "spatial addition" is in this case (and google wasn't particularly helpful), but I do understand alphablending.

If we have two images, `A` and `B`, then the resulting image `R`, when blending with alpha `a`:
`r[x, y] = a * A[x, y] + (1-a) * B[x,y];`

So, basically, adding the pixel colours together, and blending a proportion of each image. Here we're talking about RGB colours, I have absolutely no idea what happens if you do this in YUV colours - I'm sure there is some way of achieving the same thing - and it may even be called "spatial addition". But all the graphics projects I've worked on that use alpha blending have been using RGB as the intermediate terms [at least in the parts that I've touched].

I'm hoping that by describing the process, it helps you understand alphablending, and by that understand what you need to do, whether in RGB or some other format.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your prompt reply,it definitely helped alot . I have one more question which I hope that you can help : 
In terms of image processing , what does it exactly mean by adding two pixels (belonging to two different images) together ?

Comment: In the code I've worked on, literally take each colour (R, G, and B), multiply by (alpha) and (1.0-alpha) for the respective components. And yes, that will affect the intensity of both components. It should be a decent way to apply a watermark image.

Comment: Sorry and one more question , (the system wouldn't let me edit -_-")
When blending with alpha , is there a way to obtain a value for alpha such that the second image is not perceptible by the human eye and yet it is still embedded in the original image ? or is it obtained by trail and error ?

Thank you for taking your time to answer my questions .

Comment: Ah, so you are not wanting a VISIBLE water-mark? Then that's a much trickier thing to do, and I'm not at all sure how the commercial products that do this works, but I'm fairly certain that they do not use alpha blending. The naive methods, which basically just marginally alters the colours in the image doesn't work to retrieve the watermark if the image is in any way edited, such as a resave of the same image with slight size and/or compression settings changes.

Comment: Yup , I'm trying to implement a invisible watermark. The idea is to decompose an image into it's YUV components, identify keypoints in the Y component (which are invariant to attacks) using SIFT , create a Region of interest around said keypoints and perform a additive spatial watermarking. I have no idea how to implement "additive spatial watermarking" so I initially thought that alpha blending could be an alternative solution to that problem .

Comment: Sorry, can't really help on the Additive Spacial watermarking method. Never done that, but I know it's quite tricky.